# UIView not showing outlets

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode5

I have an iOS project which I moved from Xcode 4 to Xcode 5.
The problem is that when I run the project then some views don't show any UI elements like button, tableview which are also outlets. All the elements are present in ViewController Pane but they are not visible in View.

Please help me out.

Comment: check out the filesowner in the xib

Comment: no problem in that. This problem is only in two views. In rest all the views elements are visible.

Comment: ok check out those views frames

Comment: they look alright to me. 
Could you tell me if to look for anything specific??

Comment: i.e I have updated my code from xcode 4 to 5 then the mainview sizes have been modified . i.e it starts from 0,0,768,1024 to 768,0,768,1024

Comment: Hey it worked..
Could you please put your comment as answer so that I can upvote it.

Comment: I have posted the comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated my code from xcode 4 to 5 then the main view sizes have been modified . i.e it starts from 0,0,768,1024 to 768,0,768,1024 . So please check the main view frame.

Answer (score 0):

Try deselecting `Use Autolayout` in the File Inspector pane for the XIB file.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 7 uses Full layout for the view..Means Origin is behind the status bar.You can use the property and you can set like previous way as it use to work in iOS6.0

self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone